# When did "Zen" in computer programming become a thing?

Tags: history, books

What are the roots of the endless analogies to Eastern philosophy,

- [1990: Zen of Assembly Language: Volume I, Knowledge](http://www.jagregory.com/abrash-zen-of-asm/)
- [1995: Zen and the Art of the Internet: A Beginner's Guide (Prentice Hall Series in Innovative Technology)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134529146)
- [2004: Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)
- [2010: Zen of Analog Circuit Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YQ6XTW0)

Etc. I don't see this in any other industry? When did this theme start and what kicked it off?

Comment: I've always assumed that Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance was the influence for naming books this way, but it wouldn't have much to do with the form of the books.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was looking for. I never even heard of that book, and it sold 5 million copies. And it also fits the right time frame for when this seems to have been thing.

Comment: I as well assumed that it came from Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance. So +1 to Ross's comment.

Comment: Not quite fits the guidelines here: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, doesn't seem to be about computer systems, nor about software of any kind.

Comment: I'm cool with closing if it's off topic too.I didn't even know the site got on "on-topic" section.

Comment: @lvd I don't see much of a problem. "Hardware, including peripherals and Software, including operating systems and applications are in scope." If software is specifically included, it is not a stretch to include books describing techniques for writing that software.  More problematic is the relatively recent date of one of the books.  But since the first book is clearly within the "retro" range, answering the question  seems appropriate.

Comment: @lvd Pleeeeeease don't quote that! It's something that I threw together in half an hour (from some answers on [meta]) that literally nobody else has edited since; it's not representative of what actually is or isn't on-topic. [Feel free to edit it - no, _please_ edit it!](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/634/278)

Comment: @wizzwizz4: That's something that should be brought up on meta. There literally *isn't anywhere else* to look to find out what is on topic, the help page is where everybody looks.

Comment: @GregHewgill It has been brought up; I made it featured for a month, even! But nobody uses meta, unfortunately. The page is better than it used to be (zero information) but it's still not great.

Comment: I think it's a great question whether or not Retro Hacker Culture is on topic here, and if @GregHewgill wants to put that question on meta so we can hash it out, I'll read the discussion. =)

Comment: While it is valid to argue for this question to be borderling off topic, I'd put it on the good side. It is a question about culture, and Pirsig's book had a great influence on computer/ programming/ hacker culture.

Comment: Fwiw, I would agree anything relating to retro computer culture like books, demo scene, l33t HaX0rz parties and model railroading is an on topic question.

Comment: I actually checked out 'The Zen of Windows' - this is about real windows (in a house) and not computer windows!

Comment: The computer Zen appeared in the first episode of Blake's 7 in 1978.

Comment: @No'amNewman trying to get a book with a similar title published nowadays must be a real pane.

Comment: In 1969, I took exception to being called a "guru" about computers.  To me, a guru was a guy who sat in a cave staring at his navel until he suddenly got enlightenment.  I made mistakes, one after the other.  Hopefully I learned enough from each mistake to avoid repeating the same mistakes over and over.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As [Ross Ridge already mentioned](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8064/when-did-zen-in-computer-programming-become-a-thing#comment23425_8064), it's a stream of titles started with  [Robert Pirsig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_M._Pirsig)'s book [Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_and_the_Art_of_Motorcycle_Maintenance) of 1974. This book was a rather unique mixture of fiction, autobiography and philosophy focusing on what quality might be, how it's defined and what it means to people.

It was quite influential to the generation that later founded IT development during the 1980s and 1990s. So no wonder that some took the freedom to tie their works with this iconic title.

And no, it's not so much about far eastern philosophy as it seems. Beside being a fiction, it centers around classic, western philosophy.

---

**Somewhat OT:**

> I don't see this in any other industry?

Oh, don't hold your breath, there are zillions:

- [Zen and the Art of Recording](https://www.amazon.de/Zen-Art-Recording/dp/1480387436)
- [Zen and the Art of Producing](https://www.amazon.de/Zen-Art-Producing-Mixerman/dp/1458402886)
- [Zen and the Art of Mixing](https://www.amazon.de/Zen-Art-Mixing-REV-2/dp/1480366579)
- [Zen and the Art of Guitar](https://www.amazon.de/Zen-Art-Guitar-Path-Artistry/dp/0739028170)

Just a few picks from music business and there's more from [poker](https://www.amazon.de/Zen-Art-Poker-Timeless-Transform/dp/0452281261) to [table football](https://www.amazon.de/Zen-Art-Foosball-Beginners-Soccer/dp/0595217052). A great panopticon of writers who wanted to play in the same league as the original. Needless to say, only very few are worth mentioning in the same sentence as Mr. Pirsig.

Comment: It was even on the reading list of one of the CS or AI courses I took in the second half of the nineties!

Comment: Possibly coming through Danny Hillis's AI koans http://ftp.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/jargon/html/koans.html and don't forget "Zen and the art of the Macintosh" which popularized it again in 1986.

Comment: In Zen and the art of Motorcycle Maintenance, there is a chapter on the Gumption Trap.  The Gumpton Trap is relevant to software debugging, and this was realized sometime n the 1970s.

Comment: @WalterMitty - the book also describes “Stuckness”, a state that every software developer has experienced

Answer (score 22):

Pirsig's title (ZatAMM) is a quote from "[Zen in the Art of Archery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_in_the_Art_of_Archery), by Herrigel, from 1948.

Many programmers, artists, and writers (myself included) find that their best work comes when they are in a state of complete un-self-consciousness, their mind fully engaged with the task. No ego, no id, just a mental model that goes from mind to hand. Surfacing, after hours in that state, is incredibly satisfying, just like meditation.

ZatAMM may well have been the source of the reference specifically for programming. But there was already a pivot to meditative practice, since the 60's, I'd suppose. Many in the west who either dabbled with eastern religion, or independently discovered the pleasure of perfect concentration in the egoless state, made the same association, thus "Zen and {mumble}".

Comment: The idea of egoless programming was laid out in a book, The Psychology of Computer Prograsmming, by Gerald Weinberg, in 1971.

Comment: @WalterMitty Weinberg was focused on ego in the context of pride and status; that code reviewees had to put aside their ego and listen to their peer's criticism with open mind. This is certainly true, but it was not Pirsig's focus, he was more interested in the meditative state where the mind is so absorbed in a task that self disappears, time disappears, the body disappears, except as an adjunct to the tasks, e.g. reading and typing.

Answer (score 12):

On a related note, I clearly remember The Tao of Programming making the rounds on BBS in the late 80's and early 90's.  According to Wikipedia, it was written in 1987 as a bit of a spoof.  A year later the same author wrote The Zen of Programming.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tao_of_Programming

Thus spake the master programmer:

"Let the programmers be many and the managers few - then all will be productive."